# Why, dows 'neo4j console' work, and 'neo4j start' doesn't?

Tags: background, neo4j

I want to use neo4j. I installed neo4j-community 2.3.2-1 from archlinux AUR and when I ise `neo4j console`everything works fine. But when I want to start the server in the background with `neo4j start`the server won't start with error message:

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server...process [20559]... waiting for server to be ready... Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

The server did not try to start or 120 seconds, more like 2 seconds. In addition I callot find the log-files anywhere. 
Google told me to tryout `neo4j start-no-wait`
When I do this command:

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server...process [21088]...Started the server in the background, returning...
```

But nothing is started and the webclient doesn't work like it does when I use `neo4j console`.

So my basic question is: Why does `neo4j console`work and `neo4j start`does not? And how can I start neo4j in the background and stop it again without killing the process?

EDIT:
the console.log says:

```
2016-01-29 12:51:18.338+0100 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2016-01-29 12:51:18.348+0100 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@77e4c80f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@77e4c80f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@77e4c80f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@77e4c80f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log (Permission denied)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.createLogService(PlatformModule.java:261)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.<init>(PlatformModule.java:140)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.createPlatform(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.openAsOutputStream(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.io.file.Files.createOrOpenAsOuputStream(Files.java:47)
        at org.neo4j.logging.RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.openOutputFile(RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.java:254)
        at org.neo4j.logging.RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.<init>(RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.java:138)
        at org.neo4j.logging.RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.<init>(RotatingFileOutputStreamSupplier.java:122)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.logging.StoreLogService.<init>(StoreLogService.java:164)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.logging.StoreLogService.<init>(StoreLogService.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.logging.StoreLogService$Builder.toFile(StoreLogService.java:110)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.logging.StoreLogService$Builder.inStoreDirectory(StoreLogService.java:105)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.createLogService(PlatformModule.java:252)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Did you check the log? `data/log/console.log`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamLyon, I attached the console.log output of a `sudo neo4j start` call